# list different rows with the largest number

Tags: sql, max

```
select *
from list a left outer join
     twolist b
     on a.sayac = b.satir_sayac;

number    ad yazı1 yazı2
------   --- ----- ----
200222111 2 deneme renk
200222111 1 deneme önce
200789582 1 deneme sayı 
200789582 3 deneme riza
200789582 4 deneme renk
200111222 3 deneme sayı
200111222 5 deneme renk
.........................
```

ı want select max(ad)

```
200222111 2 deneme renk
200789582 4 deneme renk
200111222 5 deneme renk
```

example

why want ı select

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

A typical method uses `row_number()`:

```
select *
from list l left outer join
     (select tl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by satir_sayac order by ad desc) as seqnum
      from twolist tl
     ) b
     on l.sayac = tl.satir_sayac and tl.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
where ad= (select max(ad) from table1 t2 where t2.number=t1.number
                                          and t2.yazı1=t1.yazı1
          )
```